# Firestore: Totally disable cache for read and write

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore (from Firebase) and I have tried, without success, to disable the usage of the cache.

Here is my problem. If I disconnect my device from the internet and that I execute this ...

```
getFireStoreInstance()
    .collection(PATH)
    .document(myObject.id)
    .set(myObject)
    .addOnCompleteListener( ... )
```

or this ...

```
getFireStoreInstance()
    .collection(PATH)
    .batch()
    .update(...)
    .commit()
```

... nothing happens (which is good because I don't have any internet connection). However, as soon as I reconnect my device to the internet, the `completionListener` is called to notify me that the action has been completed.

What I would like is that, when my device does not have access to the internet, the action fails and that the `completionListener` is called with failure. Is that possible?

Of course, I have tried the following code (from [Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)) but it looks to have no effect for writing (it has effect for reading though).

```
val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build()

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().firestoreSettings = settings
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners don't ever fail due to network connectivity, and you can't change that behavior.  They always silently retry.  The whole point of having a resilient SDK like this is to prevent perceived disruption in your app when its network connection is flakey - and that happens a LOT with mobile apps.

If you require for something to fail due to lack of connectivity, make an HTTP (or callable) endpoint with Cloud Functions, and call that directly.  The call will fail if the HTTP socket can't connect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I'll handle that myself in the code

Comment: What about using [a Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for this, it will fail if internet is gone and the completionListener is called with failure

Comment: @ExocetKid You could, but transactions are inefficient, and not always the best way to perform a write.  It's up to you, but I wouldn't use a transaction unless I actually need an atomic write.

Comment: I'm leaning towards that if cache setting is off (set to persistenceEnabled: false), the pending writes feature should not be enabled, but throw. Example: An admin user removes a customer product: Cache enabled -> user sees change and thinks it's removed, Cache disabled -> user assumes write failed but takes place later. If I understand all this correctly. If cache is off, it should be off for read and write and throw, since admin user and customer will never look at the same data.